# How long does foreign DNA stay intact in human blood?

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing, hematology, parasitology

How aggressively is foreign DNA in blood targeted and degraded by the human body?

I am asking because we have a metagenomics project where we want to detect parasite DNA in the human blood. The process from DNA extraction to sequencing to bioinformatic analysis is not a problem for us. But the question is if we can expect some signal in the data.

Comment: This paper may be useful https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3728338/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [De Vlaminck Lab](https://devlaminck.bme.cornell.edu/research/) has extensively studied the origins of circulating cell-free DNA (cfDNA) in human plasma and its utility in detecting infections and organ injury.<sup>**1,2**</sup>  Concerning your question of parasite DNA detection and parsing signal from noise, I don't think you'll find a better resource than their 2020 publication in *Microbiome*.<sup>**3**</sup>

If the (uncited) claims on their website are to be believed, cfDNA from all sources is cleared within one hour after release into the blood.

> Our research pursues technologies and applications of cell-free DNA in infectious and immune-related disease. The great promise of cfDNA in diagnostic medicine derives from i) its abundance: 10-100 billion molecules of cell-free DNA can be isolated from just 1 mL of plasma. The combined DNA sequence of these molecules is sufficient to cover the human genome 1,000 to 10,000 fold. ii) Its origin: cell-free DNA is derived from dead cells and comprises rich information about cells in the blood and any vascularized tissue that can be accessed noninvasively. iii) **Its short lifetime: cell-free DNA is cleared from the blood within 60 minutes**. Cell-free DNA therefore provides a very dynamic window into health.

---

References

1. Burnham P, Kim MS, Agbor-Enoh S, Luikart H, Valantine HA, Khush KK, De Vlaminck I. **Single-stranded DNA library preparation uncovers the origin and diversity of ultrashort cell-free DNA in plasma**. *Sci Rep*. 2016 Jun 14;6:27859.
2. Cheng AP, Burnham P, Lee JR, Cheng MP, Suthanthiran M, Dadhania D, De Vlaminck I. **A cell-free DNA metagenomic sequencing assay that integrates the host injury response to infection**. *Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A*. 2019 Sep 10;116(37):18738-18744.
3. Burnham P, Gomez-Lopez N, Heyang M, Cheng AP, Lenz JS, Dadhania DM, Lee JR, Suthanthiran M, Romero R, De Vlaminck I. **Separating the signal from the noise in metagenomic cell-free DNA sequencing**. *Microbiome*. 2020 Feb 11;8(1):18.

Comment: But things like NIFT work because the foreign DNA is being constantly renewed.  Presumably non-human parasite DNA would be as well.

Comment: Thanks much! How would you inhibit the degradation of the cfDNA? EDTA and cooling? Cooling what temp?